# how to use com.jakewharton.sdkmanager when compile VLC-Android with android studio

Tags: android, compilation, vlc

I downloaded VLC-Android project, and tried to compile with android studio in WINDOWS 7(64bit). But there was a error, like this:

> Error:Could not find
>   com.jakewharton.sdkmanager:sdk-manager-plugin:1.5.0-SNAPSHOT. Searched
>   in the following locations:
>       file:/C:/Program Files/Android11/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/jakewharton/sdkmanager/sdk-manager-plugin/1.5.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
>
> ```
> file:/C:/Program Files/Android11/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/jakewharton/sdkmanager/sdk-manager-plugin/1.5.0-SNAPSHOT/sdk-manager-plugin-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
> file:/C:/Program Files/Android11/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/jakewharton/sdkmanager/sdk-manager-plugin/1.5.0-SNAPSHOT/sdk-manager-plugin-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
> file:/E:/workspace/demo/rtsp/VLC/vlc-android-master/gradle/plugins/sdk-manager-plugin-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
> file:/E:/workspace/demo/rtsp/VLC/vlc-android-master/gradle/plugins/sdk-manager-plugin.jar
> htt**ps://jcenter.bintray.com/com/jakewharton/sdkmanager/sdk-manager-plugin/1.5.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
> htt**ps://jcenter.bintray.com/com/jakewharton/sdkmanager/sdk-manager-plugin/1.5.0-SNAPSHOT/sdk-manager-plugin-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
> htt***ps://jcenter.bintray.com/com/jakewharton/sdkmanager/sdk-manager-plugin/1.5.0-SNAPSHOT/sdk-manager-plugin-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
> ```
>
> Required by:
>       :vlc-android-master:unspecified

And then I download "jakewharton sdkmanager" from github, but I cannot find these files mentioned above.

> ```
> file:/C:/Program Files/Android11/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/jakewharton/sdkmanager/sdk-manager-plugin/1.5.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml
> file:/C:/Program Files/Android11/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/jakewharton/sdkmanager/sdk-manager-plugin/1.5.0-SNAPSHOT/sdk-manager-plugin-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.pom
> file:/C:/Program Files/Android11/android-studio/gradle/m2repository/com/jakewharton/sdkmanager/sdk-manager-plugin/1.5.0-SNAPSHOT/sdk-manager-plugin-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
> file:/E:/workspace/demo/rtsp/VLC/vlc-android-master/gradle/plugins/sdk-manager-plugin-1.5.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
> file:/E:/workspace/demo/rtsp/VLC/vlc-android-master/gradle/plugins/sdk-manager-plugin.jar
> ```

I find some question similar to me, and I am not very clear with this question.
Someone said VLC-android project can only build on Linux. Is it really true?

And someone suggested me of using the compile.sh script in the repository root. But how to do this?

Can anyone let me know the process to successfully compile VLC-android project with android studio on windows.

I am newer to android and this is first time to question on StackFlow. I need you help, Please!

Comment: It will be a good idea if you will provide link of the github repository you have mentioned in your post.

Comment: Here is the link, https://github.com/JakeWharton/sdk-manager-plugin

Comment: And here is VLC-android project:  https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-android

Comment: from http://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile they say it must be run on linux. compile.sh is for linux. Maybe it would be possible to run on windows, but it would probably take a lot of effort.